# How can I make an object's key more dynamic?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an AssetManager singleton that I'm using as a data provider of sorts.

`public static var L1_1:Object = {pic:'../Assets/images/test.jpg', answer:'someAnswer', pool: 'somePool'}`

So I'm trying to use this in another class to get a path for an image class that takes a string as a param like so:

`var image:Image = new Image(AssetManager.L1_1.pic , 540, 540);`

This works great, however, I need to increment the second '1' above to make it dynamic so I can say for eg.,

`var image:Image = new Image(AssetManager.L1_5.pic , 540, 540);`

I have tried things like this, passing an imageNum property but can't sort it.

`var tempObj:Object = ['AssetManager.L' + imageNum + '_' + imageNum + '.pic'];
            trace(tempObj)`

Is there an easier way to do this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static and public properties in AS3 can be accessed using bracket syntax.

Here's an example:

```
public static var L1_1:Object = {pic:'../Assets/images/test.jpg', answer:'someAnswer', pool: 'somePool'};

var imageNum:int = 1;
var propertyName:String = "L1"+ "_" + imageNum.toString();
var tempObj:Object = AssetManager[propertyName]; 
var pathToPic:String = tempObj.pic;
trace(pathToPic);
```

The above example should trace out `../Assets/images/test.jpg`

However, be aware that bracket syntax is slower than dot syntax and is not type checked at compile time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thanks very much!  Do you know if the array I'm using below would be slower than using brackets like you mentioned?

Comment: I would guess that the array is faster, though I have not tested this. I would say that, unless speed is an issue for you, you should probably aim for whatever is easiest to read, because this will be the easiest to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix for now by simply using an array like so:

`public static var L1_1:Array = new Array(); 
        L1_1[0] = ['../Assets/images/test.jpg', "apple", "appletakeout"];`

And calling it with:

`image = new Image(AssetManager.L1_1[0][imageNum], 540, 540);`

And it works, just feels a tiny bit messy. If there's a more efficient way to do this I'd love to hear. Thanks.